# Is it fine to execute non side-effect code during assembly time?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I get a bit paranoid when I see functions like these

```
@Override
    public Mono<List<UserbaseEntityResponse.GroupPrincipal>> merge(UserbaseValidatorResult userbaseValidatorResult,
                                                                   UserbaseEntityResponse userbaseEntityResponse1,
                                                                   UserbaseEntityResponse userbaseEntityResponse2) {
        List<UserbaseEntityResponse.GroupPrincipal> conflictGroupPrincipal = new ArrayList<>();
        userbaseValidatorResult.getResult().getConflicts().forEach(conflicts -> conflicts.forEach(conflict -> {
            UserbaseEntityResponse.GroupPrincipal gp1 = findGroupPrincipalFromGroupName(userbaseEntityResponse1, conflict.getGroupName());
            UserbaseEntityResponse.GroupPrincipal gp2 = findGroupPrincipalFromGroupName(userbaseEntityResponse2, conflict.getGroupName());

            if (userbaseEntityResponse1.getUserbaseId().equals(conflict.getUserbaseId())) {
                conflictGroupPrincipal.add(ImmutableGroupPrincipal.copyOf(gp1)
                        .withName(conflict.getGroupId() + "-" + conflict.getUserbaseId()));
            } else if (userbaseEntityResponse2.getUserbaseId().equals(conflict.getUserbaseId())) {
                conflictGroupPrincipal.add(ImmutableGroupPrincipal.copyOf(gp2)
                        .withName(conflict.getGroupId() + "-" + conflict.getUserbaseId()));
            }

        }));

        return Mono.just(conflictGroupPrincipal);
    }
```

All the code above return statement is not wrapped in Mono and I think all statements get executed during assembly time. Since there are no side-effects in any of these operations is it fine?

A bigger question is when should we wrap methods inside defer like below

```
public Mono<List<>> merge(args...) {
  return Mono.defer(() -> doMerge(args...));
}

public List<> doMerge(args...) {
  // business logic
}
```

My understanding is, whenever we make n/w operations we should defer the execution. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you provided is what I like to call an "Imposter Reactive Method".  It's really just a synchronous method that happens to return a reactive publisher.

Imposter Reactive Methods have a few disadvantages:

1. "Work" is being performed at assembly time, which violates the "[nothing happens until you subscribe](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe)" design of reactive streams
2. The "Work" cannot be deferred to another thread via `.subscribeOn` on the returned `Mono`.  So if any of the functionality performed within the method is blocking, it might block the event loop.
3. The "resilience" operators like `.timeout`, `.repeat`, and `.retry` operators will not work on the returned `Mono`.

At a bare minimum, you can use `Mono.fromCallable` like this:

```java
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

    // ... snip ... construct conflictGroupPrincipal...

    return conflictGroupPrincipal;
});
```

You can also use `Mono.defer` like you mentioned, but that is overkill in this case, since the implementation is synchronous.

(P.S. You might also find [this presentation](https://youtu.be/xCu73WVg8Ps?t=1258) useful, where I cover Imposter Reactive Methods in more detail.)

Comment: graat talk, simple and informative, fun to see blizzard jumping on the reactive train

Comment: Got it thanks for the explanation. Another question, if we have Monos like below ```public Mono<ImmutableJobBean> execute(JobBean job) {
    Mono<Tuple2<UserbaseEntityResponse, UserbaseEntityResponse>> userbaseEntityTuple = Mono.zip…


    Mono<UserbaseEntityResponse> result = userbaseEntityTuple.flatMap…

    Mono<ImmutableJobBean> nextJob = Mono.just…

    return nextJob.zipWith…..;
}``` Even that is considered as "Imposter Reactive Method" ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from that snippet, but generally as long as the method is dedicated to assembling a stream using reactive operators, and not performing other "work", it's ok.